# JavaScript or Notepad++ regular expression to add thousands separator to arbitrary text

Tags: javascript, regex, notepad++

As part of a visualisation, I'd like to add thousands separators to any numbers (contiguous string of digits) in a string. It needn't consider the context of the number e.g.

```
1234e+56789 Nokia 3210s cost $123456.7890 and my phone number is 123-4567-89012.
```

becomes

```
1,234e+56,789 Nokia 3,210s cost $123,456.7,890 and my phone number is 123-4,567-89,012.
```

I know I can reverse the string, replace `\d{3}(?=\d)` with `$&,` and reverse it again, but is there a way to do it with regular expressions only (preferably just one)?

Comment: Looks like Notepad++ does not support positive lookaheads...so might be better writing a little script.

Comment: @epascarello it sure does. make sure to updated to NP++ 6.

Comment: AH I am sitting on 5.X :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty much the same as your attempt, just reversed and with a quantifier:

```
\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))
```

And replace that with `$&,`.

The `(?:\d{3})+` makes sure that there is a multiple of 3 digits following and the `(?!\d)` then makes sure that there is no fourth or fifth digit following.

If you want to use this in Notepad++ make sure to upgrade to version 6.

Note that in Notepad++ you could also use a lookbehind:

```
(?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))
```

And replace that with `,`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this expression:

```
((?<=\d)\d{3}(?=\D|(?:\d{3})*(?:\D|$)))
```

And replace by `,$1`.

The lookbehind makes sure there's a number before the 3 digits we're matching.

The 3 digits we're matching are the 'thousands' you want to put a comma before.

The lookahead makes sure there's either a non-digit after, or a set of triplets of digits.

Comment: Thanks. As m.buettner noted, Notepad++ 6 is needed for look-behind.

Comment: @Gnubie Yes, I didn't know you were on earlier versions. His expression is better than mine anyway :)